# Easiest way to create an animated 3D cartoon

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, 3d, blender

I was wondering, what is the easiest way to create an animated 3D cartoon. I want to create a character which moves and talk. I am not familiar with an easy way to do it, I used Blender and Unity but I was wondering if there is an easy way to do it? as I believe that not everyone doing 3D cartons have to dig deep in coding, they certainly use a software/GUI or something to create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what **easy** is defined for peole but someway might be easy for me , it may be hard for you. I think it is based on experience in the past.

If you want to create a custom 3d animated model, you need to model it first. Or you can find a 3d model which is similar to your model, so you can edit it. But you are going to use a 3d modeling programs like; Blender, 3ds Max, even SketchUp might work.

> One easy way. Which requires less work

You can check [Adobe Fuse](http://www.adobe.com/tr/products/fuse.html). Which lets you select predefined parts and lets you create a 3d humanoid model. You can tweak them a bit. After completing you can export it to [Mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com/) where you can rig your model (also you can select premade models here). They have alot of animations to go. After selecting your animations you can import it to Unity.

> Animation techniques

For most of them, you will need rigs. When you rigged a model, you can create animations with those rigs.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7OThj13tPq8) is my one of the old works from university.(Ignore the music please :D) Before i make the animations, I've recorded myself on the exact angle with model, (Front and side 2 videos) and used my video as refence while animating. To conclude i used **key frames**. And Blender made the rest (making transaction between keyframes). This is one of the techniques.

--**EDIT**--

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQgRzfISz-E&list=PL4Nyr68qAlI1gEBSGHJwo2p-GS6ShZhYL) might give you more information about the video referencing.

---

More budgeted projects mostly use mo-cap. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_7CfWlkqm8) is one example for facial animation.

There are also cheaper infrared cameras like Kinect which allows you to do mo-cap. But results are not that promising. You can find more than few assets in the Unity Store. But i suggest you to use at least 2 cameras if you choose this way.

There might be more ways to create 3d model animation. I am not an animator. But those are that i know.

Hope this helps! Cheers!